# OpenGL : Mesh turns black when adding specular lighting

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I have implemented specular lighting in my C++ openGL program but when i add the final specular value into my existing diffuse lit equation, it turns black.
 Just displaying the specular on the mesh also doesnt work and the mesh remains back and removing the specular form the final equation for the `Pixel` restores the Non specular lighting.
**How do i Fix this**
These are the shaders.

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 pos;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 coords;
layout (location = 2) in vec3 normals;

out vec2 Texture_Coords;
out vec3 normal;
out vec3 toLightVector;
out vec3 toCameraVector;

uniform mat4 p;
uniform mat4 m;
uniform mat4 v;
uniform vec3 light_position;

void main(){
    vec4 world_position = m * vec4(pos,1.0);

    //unrelated working stuff

    toCameraVector = (inverse(v) * vec4(0,0,0,1)).xyz - world_position.xyz;
}
```

```
#version 330 core

out vec4 Pixel;

in vec2 Texture_Coords;
in vec3 normal;
in vec3 toLightVector;
in vec3 toCameraVector;

uniform vec4 color;
uniform sampler2D Texture;
uniform float ambient;
uniform vec3 light_color;
uniform float reflective;
uniform float specular;

void main(){
    vec3 unitToCameraVector = normalize(toCameraVector);
    //unrelated working stuff
    vec3 light_direction = -unitToLightVector;

    vec3 reflection = reflect(light_direction, unitNormal);
    float specular_factor = dot(reflection, unitToCameraVector);
    specular_factor = max(specular, 0.0);

    float damped_specular = pow(specular_factor, specular);
    vec3 final_specular = damped_specular * light_color;

    Pixel = vec4(diffuse,1.0) * texture(Texture, Texture_Coords) + vec4(final_specular, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: Does the shader compile without errors? For me it doesn't.

Comment: i Get no errors @BDL

Comment: But your fragment shader uses variables that you never declared? For example, `unitToLightVector`, `unitNormal`. Are you checking for compile errors by calling `glGetShaderiv` with the `GL_COMPILE_STATUS` parameter as described here: https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Compilation#Shader_error_handling ?

Comment: @BDL those declarations have been removed for brevity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there's a typo ? The statement

```
specular_factor = max(specular, 0.0);
```

looks like it should be :

```
specular_factor = max(specular_factor, 0.0);
```

Comment: There is a recommendation not to answer typo-question. Questions like these are off-topic and should not be answered but closed as they are not helpful to other contributors. The questions will be closed and finally deleted. If the question is deleted, your gained reputation points will be lost.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I am sorry, I am still learning how to ask better questions.

Comment: @ExtorcProductions Glad if I could help, but maybe you could move ahead of the moderators and delete your own question ?